# Text Not Wrapping Around Right Floated Image

Tags: css, templates

I created a page where I have text wrapping around a right floated image using shape-outside polygon (yes, I will be using the cross-browser polyfill). Outside of Wordpress it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lkhrmr1/ The problem is when I put it into a Wordpress template http://stage.metooplace.com/discover-your-story/. I done lots of searching, but I can't seem to figure out why it won't wrap.

FYI: I'm using using the Underscores blank theme.

Any ideas?

Comment: It didn't start off that way because I wasn't sure if it was an issue with Wordpress or not, but it had to do with a 3rd party theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your heading is clearing the float. This is in your stylesheet:

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    clear: both;
}
```

You'll need to get rid of that, or overwrite it in this context, to allow headings to wrap around floated images.

Comment: That was it and part of the Underscores blank theme.

Comment: Hm, weird choice in their part. Can imagine plenty of scenarios where theme authors and users would want headings to wrap around things.